# Use sharepoint apps over internet (use wildcard domain ?)

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, domain, internet

As I cannot find answers on the web, I seeking for help here. Sorry for my bad English.

I have a SharePoint 2013 on premise with SSL apps fully working in my company network. 
The SharePoint web application are published on internet and they work well too except for apps access.

Ok, lets say my domain is `contoso.com` and my apps domain is `contosoapp.com`.
I've publish my web application URL `https://project.contoso.com` but how can I publish my app domain?

In my understanding it's not possible to publish a wildcard URL like `*.contosoapp.com` on the web. This is what we do on our internal DNS, but how to do that over the web?

So am I missing some SharePoint or DNS configuration? AS every apps URL will be different how can I do?

Comment: I was wondering this too. Do SharePoint 2013 apps need the client browser to resolve app domain hostnames and connect directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finaly found why my public DNS did not allow me to create a wildcard entry! It's because I had an other entry on this domain... The app's domain need to be totally empty to add *.contosoapp. So simple! I was too much looking the SharePoint side.